# Workaround when gzip is not enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, gzip

My hosting company do not have gzip enabled for various reasons. Can I manually per-compress JS and CSS files and then serve them to clients which accept gziped files?

Alternatively is there any code snippets to perform gzip compression on the fly within the application code?

Using MVC3 C#, have no access to ISS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If the files you want to serve are fixed, you should be able to compress elsewhere and upload them without any trouble.

Comment: What about serving uncompress files to browsers that don't support gzip? Are there any worthwhile browsers that don't support gzip?

Comment: Essentially all browsers, worthwhile or not, support gzip.  See http://www.vervestudios.co/projects/compression-tests/results .